# How can I set same Property in two different classes?

Tags: java

I have two java classes. Some of the properties have the same name. But these classes are generated so I can't put the properties in a parent class.

Is there are possibility to use a method to set same properties only one time?

```
Class A {
  String Same1 = "";
  String Same2 = "";
  String AOther1 = "";
  String AOther2 = "";
}

Class B {
  String Same1 = "";
  String Same2 = "";
  String BOther1 = "";
  String BOther2 = "";
}
```

this I don't want:

```
{
  a.setSame1("xyz");
  a.setSame2("xyz");
  a.setAOther1("xyz");
  a.setAOther2("xyz");

  b.setSame1("xyz");
  b.setSame2("xyz");
  b.setBOther1("xyz");
  b.setBOther2("xyz");
}
```

I want to do it like this:

```
private Object same(String iClass) {
  Object ret = null;
  if ("A".equals(iClass)) {
    ret = new A();
  }
  if ("B".equals(iClass)) {
    ret = new B();
  }
  ret.setSame1("xyz");  <-- Here I get "cannot find symbol". Object has no "same1" property
  ret.setSame2("xyz");
  return ret;
}

{
  A a = this.same("A");
  a.setAOther1("xyz");
  a.setAOther2("xyz");

  B b = this.same("B");
  b.setBOther1("xyz");
  b.setBOther2("xyz");
}
```

Comment: If the classes share no common parents, then those fields are *unrelated*. The fact that they have the same name is not a concern for the JVM; they're two completely distinct fields. You can probably do some deep shenanigans with reflection to pretend they're related, but the right answer here is definitely: have a common superclass or interface.

Comment: Strong hints that we might be deal with an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here: what are you doing that you're working with generated classes instead of classes that are under your control?

Comment: Especially given that you can't generate classes that match your problem? The point of code generation is: to give you something useful to work with. When the stuff that gets generated isn't useful ... then consider to talk to the people that generate that code.

Comment: And note: when you do `Object ret = whatsoever` ... then it really doesn't matter to the Java compiler what happens on the right hand side of that assignment. The compiler only "remembers" that `ret` is of type Object. And Object doesn't have those fields and setters. Java is a statically typed language that doesn't support "duck typing". Silvio nailed it: your classes A and B have no conceptual relationships, field names are meaningless. Finally, yes, reflection could work (well) here ... but with reflection, you always have to know what you are doing. And I somehow wonder about that point.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not very well generated. But we don't have the possibility to change that. I had wrote that in my question! Comments like, change the generator is not helpful. Because we cannot!!! It's from external library. I test the reflection. Thank you

Comment: If the number of generated classes are limited, I'd stick to something like `ABBuilder.create(same1, same2).buildA();` or `ab.buildB();` if you're not at the point where deep diving into reflection is worth while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help!

I found a solution that is very easy. Reflections not work.

```
Class<?> c = returnObj.getClass();
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("setSame1", String.class);
method.invoke(returnObj, "Here a Test");
```